# string::erase(0) on an empty string?

Tags: c++, string, erase

Is the behaviour of `std::string::erase(0)` is well defined on an empty string. Because [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase) says:

```
Removes count characters starting at index.
```

But for an empty string, the character at index 0 does not exist.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems to be OK, since the size of the string is `0`:

> **21.4.6.5 basic_string::erase [string::erase]**
>
> `basic_string<charT,traits,Allocator>& erase(size_type pos = 0, size_type n = npos);`
>
> 1 Requires: `pos <= size()`
>
> 2 Throws: out_of_range if `pos > size()`.

Answer (score 4):

On the same page of [`std::string::erase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase) I found these lines:

> **Exceptions**
>   1)     std::out_of_range if `index > size()`.
>   2-3) (none)